# Allow whitespace, unicode letters, digits, underscore, dash AND comma?

Tags: php, regex, unicode, preg-match

I'm pretty new at the subject `preg` and I'm using this `preg_match` condition to check if the user has entered whitespace, unicode letters, digits, underscore or dash:

```
if(preg_match("/[^\040\pL\pN_-]/u", $term)) {
```

But now I wanted to allow a comma. So I tried this:

```
if(preg_match("/[^\040\pL\pN,_-]/u", $term)) {
```

And it actually works and I just wanted to know **why**. I just want to understand it better. Why does it have to be `,_-` and not `-_,` for example to allow the comma?

I would really appreciate if someone could explain this to me step by step.

Comment: as an aside, instead of writing `\pL\pN_` in unicode mode, you can write `\w`, it's exactly the same. An other possible place for `-` is immediately after a shorthand character class. So you can write `[^\040\pL\pN-_,]` or `[^\040\pL-\pN_,]` too. It works the same with ranges `[a-z-,]` is possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because `-` is used for ranges in square brackets(`[]` -> character classes). And as from the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.meta.php): `indicates character range`, example: `0-9` or `a-z`.

So as long as you put it at the end you're fine and don't have to escape it. In all other cases you have to escape it with a backslash e.g. `\-`.

Means:

```
,_-  //At the end
_,-  //At the end
\-,_ //Escape it
\-_, //Escape it
,\-_ //Escape it
_\-- //Escape it
```

Comment: Perhaps you should mention `_,-` is also correct, it should be clear to the OP that the elements inside `[]`  act like a commutative set.

Comment: @ShellFish yeah, I hoped that: *if you put them at the end* was clear enough, but I will rephrase my answer a bit to make it more clearer.

Comment: @Vaia You're welcome. (BTW: I can also highly recommend you this site: https://regex101.com/ which gives always a good explanation what your regex does. E.g. `-` unescaped: https://regex101.com/r/mP6hW9/1 `-` escaped: https://regex101.com/r/mP6hW9/2 `-` at the end: https://regex101.com/r/mP6hW9/3)

Answer (score 0):

When we're working inside brackets or with a character class, `-` indicates a character range, like `[a-z]`. Therefore, if you place a dash anywhere but at the very end of the character class, it will not be interpreted as a literal dash, but instead as a character range indicator.

Comment: That means `-` has to be at the end every time?

Comment: @Vaia No it's just so, that if you don't want it to use it as a character range you have to escape it with a backslash, if it is not at the end

Comment: What he said, either place it in the end or escape it. I like to place it in the end, avoid that extra escape, as it doesn't really add to regex readability.